# Questions where I have left a comment

Tags: support, comments

I would like to be able to locate those questions to which I have left a comment,
Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your user profile, under the activity tab, under the all actions tab, you'll find [a tab](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=comments) listing all your comments.